# Why does union not return a unique list?

Tags: common-lisp

Is there a logical reason why the following statement from the Hyperspec is the way it is?
"If there is a duplication between list-1 and list-2, only one of the duplicate instances will be in the result. If either list-1 or list-2 has duplicate entries within it, the redundant entries might or might not appear in the result."

Until I read this I was assuming that union should return a unique list and frustrated why my code didn't do so. It also seems odd to remove duplicates between lists but not within. Why even specify this?

It seems like one should be able to assume union will produce a unique list of the set's elements or am I missing something?

For the full page in Hyperspec see http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_unionc.htm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your code has sets only with unique elements (like `1 2 3` ), then `UNION` will preserve this property.

If your code has sets with non-unique elements (like `1 2 2 3` ), then `UNION` does not need to make any effort to enforce uniqueness in the result set.

Removing duplicates is done with a separate function: `REMOVE-DUPLICATES`.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that elements of both lists that are arguments to UNION are unique means that the complexity of the algorithm in the worst case (non-sortable, non-hashable elements) is O(n*m). On the other hand removing duplicates in a list in that case is O(n^2). Making UNION remove duplicates would approximately triple the running time even in the case where there were no duplicates, since most of the time is consumed by doing the comparisons.

Comment: Why not just append the two lists then that should take O(1) time?
The requirement for no dupes between lists prevents this so that is probably why it was included in spec; buy why?

Comment: Because APPEND is not UNION. Union is a set operation, and when called on sets (that is, lists of elements unique under :test), it performs the set operation. The specification permits UNION to not enforce that the arguments are logical sets, since that is expensive. (Also in CL APPEND in O(n) where n is the length of all but first argument. There are no real lists in default CL).

Comment: Errr... @Ramarren... How is a linked list "not a real list"? Admittedly, there's no pointer to tail (at least not by default), but I have a hard time seeing them as anything but real.

Comment: It is a bit of an exaggeration and abusing the word "real". And I suppose reality of the lists is only loosely related to complexity of APPEND. But the issue is really with the default type hierarchy, which was built for compatibility with older Lisps. In CL the LIST type is not a list, it is an union of CONS and NULL, which is a superset of actual ("proper") lists. The level at which lists are represented in CL is too low, and there are a lot of cases where this representation cannot be ignored (e.g why you cannot mutate an empty list).